# Создать конфиг для изменение размера списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня такая проблема: я запуская одну exe с 2-мя параметрами и потом все это читаю в ответ. Ответ выглядит примерно вот так:

```
GetUnitInfo ErrorCode=0
<UnitInfo><UnitData><Value>WO</Value><Value>PartNumber = "Sing/Dual/Prot" Firmware = "ExempleFirmware" /></Value></UnitData></UnitInfo>
```

Код:

```
 os.system(link_getunit+" "+Param+" "+VerificareSN+" -a >result_container.txt")
        print(Pass+"Executed GetUnitInfo")
    L1=[]
    L2=[]
    with open('result_container.txt') as file:
        L1 = str(file.readline())
        L2 = str(file.readline())
        file.close()
    if L1[0:23] == "GetUnitInfo ErrorCode=0" :
```

Меня интересует `PartNumber = "Sing/Dual/Prot"` и   `Firmware = "ExempleFirmware"`
Я читаю из списка `L2` по длины  `L2[21;5]` , но длина может менятся и не совпасть с мойм `If`.
Подскажите пожалуйста как создать конфиг, в котором я могу изменить длину `L1` и `L2` в зависимости от ситуации?

Comment: Ну может регулярные выражения использовать или писать данные в виде какой-то стандартной структуры `JSON` или там `XML`, для них есть стандартные вполне парсеры.

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное , re.search()  помогло мне!